# Is it possible to replace the hard drive on a Inspiron 13 7000?

Tags: dell-inspiron

Is it possible to replace the hard drive on a Inspiron 13 7000? I'm considering getting one, but I'd likely want to pop in a big SSD in there. Is it possible to do that or is the HD soldered or of a weird form factor?

Comment: I'm not sure if I bought exactly that model, but I bought a Dell and changed the hard drive, so, thank you @davidbaumann.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dell devices are mostly well documented.

I thin it's the device you consider to buy: [Service manual](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-13-7347-laptop_Service%20Manual_en-us.pdf)

It's very easy to swap the harddrive.